# Can I use the word "softworks"?

Tags: word-usage

I see Bethesda Softworks, a well-known video game publisher, uses the word as a part of its name, and I'm pretty sure it's made up, but I like it. I would like to use it in the same sense as they do, to describe what my studio focuses on, software. Am I "allowed" gramatically to use the word as a reference to software work? Is it frowned upon?

Comment: They have a registration mark on Bethesda. I don't see one on softworks, and a Google search reveals many examples of other "softworks". Ask your lawyer.

Comment: I wasn't really asking on a legal basis, it seems harmless to me. Just wanted to check if it would make sense to people why it's there, if it's a good fit grammatically.

Comment: It's a [portmanteau](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portmanteau).

Comment: Alright, thanks. Can you add that as an answer?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about legal usage of a term, not language *per se*.

Comment: (And if it's not, you should edit your comment into your question to make it clear what you're really asking about; as written, the question clearly refers to the legality of being "allowed" to do so.)

Comment: ...except that it first must be established that _softworks_ is not in widespread generic use, which means the question isn't off-topic.

Comment: I started trading under the name *Softworks* almost 30 years ago, as an independent custom software supplier. But after a few years I decided I might as well use my own name - there were no obvious advantages to having a trading name, and one big *disadvantage* was no bank would give me free banking.

Comment: @Hellion, I edited the question, it's now not ambiguous whether it's a legal question. Can you please remove the hold?

Comment: @HenriqueP., I can't remove the hold singlehandedly (just as I couldn't place it singlehandedly), but I nominated it for reopening, at least.  :-)

Comment: Doesn't really make sense that people can easily mark it as off-topic, but reverting it seems impossible. Oh well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The word "softworks" appears to be a [portmanteau](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portmanteau) of *software* and *works*. I also note that "Bethesda®" is a registered trade mark, and "softworks" is not (in fact a Google search yields many organizations using the name "softworks"). I believe your usage of the term is unrestricted, but I have not performed an in-depth trade dress search.